# Expire php session variable after period of time

Tags: php, apache, session

Is there a way to set a php session variable (`$_SESSION['example'`) to expire after a given amount of time. To clarify, **I want to keep the user's session intact and keep all other variables with their values**, I only want to set a single session variable to expire after a short time period (1 minute or so). Is there any way to set the variable to expire on its own or will I have to keep track of time and delete the variable when I have determined that the time has expired? I am using php 5 with apache2 on ubuntu. Thanks.

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I specifically asked to keep the session alive along with all other session variables while only deleting a single variable.

Comment: You could achieve this with cookies... not sure if that's the direction you want to go

Comment: Maybe look into using some sort of memory cache (like Redis) as a means to achieve the expiration effect.

Comment: You can store a expiry date in your session and clean the variable if the expiry date is in the past. There is an example of code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes/1270960#1270960

Comment: Actually, you only need to determine if it has expired when it is used. So keep a time of 'last access' against it. When it is accessed then check the `last access time`. Delete it if it is too old. i.e. return nothing.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe do something like :

```
$_SESSION['example'] = $value;
$_SESSION['expiries']["example"] = time() + 30*60; // 30 mins
```

Declare function:

```
function expireSessionKeys() {
     foreach ($_SESSION["expiries"] as $key => $value) {
          if (time() > $value) { 
             unset($_SESSION[$key]);
          }
     }
}
```

Then wherever you have `session_start()` follow it up with `exprireSessionKeys()`

All this can be built in a custom [session handler](http://php.net/manual/en/class.sessionhandler.php)

Comment: Thanks. Very useful to implement when need to show messages on a refreshed page.